# Estimate SQL Server CE Database size

Tags: sql, database, size, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have written a program to estimate the size of a SQL Server CE 2008 database based on the stops outlined in the article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827968

I do have the following queries.

1. The database is used for desktop applications and hence I use the connection string to set the max database size to 4091. now when i run my estimation program, I get an output which is close to 8GB of used space. Why am I not getting any space related exceptions?
2. The `.sdf` file size is just 156 MB. So how does this compare to the 8GB of used space?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if your estimate is 8GB however the .sdf file is 156MB, I would expect a problem in your estimation since reality and events always trump predictions of what may happen.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't get any exceptions because you set a max size of 4096 and the actual size, by your own data, is only  156.  The database engine is unaware of your estimation, it only cares about the actual size, which is less that what your connection string says should be the maximum.
2. How does it compare?  156MB is less than 8GB.

You've not show us anything about your estimation algorithm.  All we can deduce from what information you do give is that it's wildly wrong.  It's a near certainly that you have a mistake in your code, your assumptions, or both.